# How create separate sqlite file with self model

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nspersistentstore

I have read this post [Core Data with mutiple sqlite files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323203/core-data-with-mutiple-sqlite-files) and some else.

However not find any intelligible information about creation separated sqlite files (for example to store some data for different users). That's what I'm doing:

```
- (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
{
    if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
    {
        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }
    NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.sqlite", _userID]];


    __persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    }
    return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
}

- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }

    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"DataBase" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];
    return __managedObjectModel;
}

- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    if (__managedObjectContext != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectContext;
    }

    NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *coordinator = [self persistentStoreCoordinator];

    if (coordinator != nil)
    {
            __managedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
            [__managedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:coordinator];   
    }
    return __managedObjectContext;
}
```

If you change the user also changes `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` and `NSManagedObjectContext` but `NSManagedObjectModel` - not (there `NSFetchRequest`). So how to separate core data (with self data and the "fetch requests") for different user without creating additionally entity(like user)?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use multiple contexts with their own stores, but based on the same data model. In this way you could use the same entities for the different stores.

Comment: Just like in your code, only several times: persistenStoreCoordinator1, managedObjectContext1; persistenStoreCoordinator2, managedObjectContext2; etc.

Comment: Did you read what I wrote?
You do not understand me, I think... I do not need multiple stores in one time! I don't need any 1,2,3... variables! Because persistenStoreCoordinator and managedObjectContext are released any time and spawn with different `storeURL`. I.e. one user is entered (with his storeURL) and logout, after that another entered (with other storeURL). I need to separate their data

Comment: If everything works as posted above, then "first" user can see all the data, but others don't see anything (and everything that they change only appears for "first" user)